# Passing Parameters in .onaction event for shortcutmenu/commandbar

Tags: vba

I have some custom shortcut menus that will call some functions. In the past I've always used functions that don't take any inputs, but I'm trying to use inputs on these functions and it doesn't seem to like it. here's the code:

```
Sub fRunDataGraphC2Flow() 

Dim cmbshortcutmenu As Office.CommandBar
Dim cmbControl As Office.CommandBarControl
Set cmbshortcutmenu = CommandBars.Add("fRunDataGraphC2Flow", msoBarPopup, False, False)
'Copy Command
cmbshortcutmenu.Controls.Add Type:=msoControlButton, Id:=19
'Adjust Axes
'function = AdjustAxis("C2Flow")
Set cmbControl = cmbshortcutmenu.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
With cmbControl
    .Caption = "Adjust Axis"
    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
    .OnAction = "AdjustAxis(""C2Flow"")"
    .FaceId = 625
    .BeginGroup = True
End With
```

...

When I try and use the command "Adjust Axis" I get the following error:

Microsoft Access cannot run the macro or callback function 'AdjustAxis("C2flow")' Make sure the macro or function exists and takes the correct parameters. The function is designed to take a string. So it should accept this, but I wonder if the quotation marks are confusing it.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: `When I try and use the command "Adjust Axis"` <-- how are you actually using this function? Your code is confusing to me since you've commented the line which presumably is causing the error out so I don't know what you are doing. Probably  you need to remove `function =` and just leave that line as `AdjustAxis("C2Flow")`.

Comment: The comments are just for my own use.  The code causing the problem is:

Comment: .OnAction = "AdjustAxis(""C2Flow"")"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.OnAction = "'AdjustAxis ""C2Flow""'"
```

Example:

```
Sub y()
    Dim CBar As CommandBar
    Dim Ctl As CommandBarControl

    Set CBar = CommandBars("Cell")
    Set Ctl = CBar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 19)
    With Ctl
        .Caption = "X"
        .OnAction = "'x ""Hello World!""'"
    End With
End Sub

Sub x(s As String)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error that you get? Look at my edited post - the code in my example works.

Comment: I added    .OnAction = "'AdjustAxis ""C2Flow""'", and I switched the AdjustAxis from a function to a sub.   the error I get is :  "Microsoft Access cannot run the macro or callback function 'AdjustAxis("C2flow")' Make sure the macro or function exists and takes the correct parameters. "

Comment: Scuse me, that last part shouldn't have the parentheses

Comment: Maybe you marked it as `Private`? I'm doing my testing in Excel, but I don't think it will be different in Access.